# use Redux::setOption to save value in media option

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I use below code to save value to Media type option in redux framework. it  save in database but I can not see it in redux options. Media type has ID and URL that should be saved on database but with this code, can not do that.

```
Redux::setOption('sample_options','sample_favicon', 'http://URL_TO_IMAGE');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this

```
  $option_array   =   array('url'=>$option_value);
  Redux::setOption('sample_options','sample_favicon', $option_array);
```

replace $option_value with your image path.